Evaluate geometry nodes for individual instances
I have created tiles using Instance on Points node. I want to animate tiles that just move from top to bottom. I want some kind of easing, so I'm sampling Bezier curve(s). I thought I can do this by adding random Z variations to the starting point of each curve and by controlling the factor of the Sample Curve node. With the setup I made, all the tiles are moving together, so it seems that a single Bezier curve is sampled and that bottom part of the nodes aren't evaluated for every individual instance, or I'm doing something wrong.
Without adding the Integer ID node, the link between the Random Value and the Start Point of the Bezier curve is invalid saying that "The node input does not support fields"
If I connect a Random Value to the Offset of the Set Position node, then I can see the random variations of the tiles in Z.
What I want to achieve is:
Have the tiles in different Z starting positions.
Animate them to reach the end position in the same time.
Have non-linear animation, possibly by sampling the Bezier curve.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It should look something similar to this at start:


Do you want "for a single tile" the speed to be randomized? Accelerate, brake, accelerate, brake?

The problem with nodes that output geometry is that they rarely output multiple geometries, just a single geometry (and that is related to "doesn't accept fields" message).
You can instead have a single unit bezier curve and multiply the random value after sampling the curve:


Thanks a lot! This solved the problem!
